# Let S be a set. If $S$ has $n$ elements, then S has $2^n$ subsets proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading a book and this I've been stuck on this proof for hours:

[image]

I cant understand what set is $V$ and what set is $W.$
$V$ is the set of all the subsets of $S$ (the power set) "and $a_{n+1}\notin S$" what does that "and .." mean? I don't really get it, is it $S$ without $a_{n+1}$?

Then, another question, I don't really understand that function, if $s_n=\{1,2\}$, for example, then its power set is $\mathcal{P}(S_n)=\{\phi, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\}$, now this is the domain of that function, and the range is $\{\{3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$ but how is this the same as "a mapping from $V$ onto $W$"?? maybe I don't understand this because I don't understand how $V$ and $W$ are defined.

Comment: This is a *proof by induction*.  Have you ever heard that phrase before?

Comment: @JMoravitz yes and? I just gave an example with n=2 to understand better

Comment: Maybe $a_{n+1}\not\in \color{red}X$ instead of $\color{blue}S$ was intended in the definitions of $V$ and $W$.  What book is this?

Comment: So, we are curious how many subsets $\{1,2,3\}$ has.  To count this, we look at the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ which explicitly don't include $3$ and the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ which explicitly do include $3$.  Counting the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ which don't include $3$ is easy since that is exactly our induction hypothesis... it is simply the subsets of $\{1,2\}$, i.e. $2^2$.  Then counting the subsets which explicitly do contain $3$ can be reworded as the other since there is a bijection as described above so it must be the same number as the other set, so also $2^2$.  Adding these gives $2^3$

Comment: Please, since you know how to use basic mathjax, use it completely; and please don't be sloppy with "i dont...".  Rather, write "I don't...". I'm not always keen to clean up after sloppy posts, when a poster knows better.

Comment: $a_{n+1}\in(\text{or }\not\in) S$ should be $a_{n+1}\in X$.

Comment: The argument works for $\{1,2,\dots,n,n+1\}$ as well.  Counting the number of subsets without $n+1$ is the induction hypothesis and contributes $2^n$ to the sum.  Then, recognizing the bijection, the number of subsets *with* $n+1$ as an element is *also* $2^n$.  Adding gives $2^{n+1}$, completing the proof.

Comment: I think it's supposed to say $a_{n+1}\in X$ for $V$ and $a_{n+1}\notin X$ for $W$.  What is written makes no sense.

Comment: @saulspatz so there is a typo in the book!?

Comment: Yes.  There is a typo in both places.

Comment: @saulspatz .. I can't believe it.. thank you!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner learning to reason by Nancy rodgers

Comment: @NelliKuukeri or if you want I can select your comment as best answer but I dont know how to do it

Comment: It's not that good. :)

Comment: @cekami7844 You might want to check the errata for this book (if there's one)

Answer (score 2):

There is a typographical mistake:

$V=\{X\subseteq S:a_{n+1}\notin X\}$ and
$W=\{X\subseteq S:a_{n+1}\in X\}$

Next, if we put $n=2$ then $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $S_2=\{1,2\}$. Then
$V=\mathcal{P}(S_2)=\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ and $W=\{\{3\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.
So the $f$ maps following:

$f:\emptyset\mapsto \{3\}$
$f:\{1\}\mapsto \{1,3\}$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What characterizes a subset of $S$? It is a set $ T$ of elements each of which belons to $S.$ So how do you build such a $T$ from $S?$ You look at every member of $S$ and ask "Does this member belong to $T$? The answer is "Yes" or "No." Since $S$ contains $n$ members the number of different possibilities for "yes"or "No","yes"or "No",...,"yes"or "No" is $2\times2\times\dots\times2=2^n$ because there are $n$ $2$'s in the product. So the number of subsets of S is $2^n.$

Answer (score 0):

As @AVISEKSHARMA notes, $\notin S$ and $\in S$ should respectively read $\notin X$ and $\in X$. So $V$ is the set of subsets of $S$ that *don't* have $a_{n+1}$ as an element, and $W$ is the set of subsets of $S$ that *do* have $a_{n+1}$ as an element. We biject $V$ with $W$ using $f(A)=A\cup\{a_{n+1}\}$ for each $A\in V$. But the inductive step also uses the fact that $V$ has $2^n$ elements, because it happens to also be the powerset of a set with $n$ elements: that set is $S\setminus\{a_{n+1}\}$.